# Clonezilla and GParted on one USB stick

Tags: gparted, clonezilla

I want to have Clonezilla and GParted on one USB stick. I remember that there was a joint project, but it is now closed. Is there an ISO with both that I can download?

I don't want a multiboot USB. I want one Linux with both tools.
Sorry for the [link in German](http://www.linux-community.de/ausgaben/linuxuser/2007/07/gparted-und-clonezilla-im-duo-auf-einer-live-cd/), but this was the project in 2007 which mentioned.

Comment: Try with [MultibootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/) (and a Clonezilla iso file and another iso file with gparted).

Comment: @S_Flash I'm not convinced that this is what is being asked. It seems to me that the asker wants to combine both Clonezilla live USB and GParted live USB on one multiboot USB flash drive and select which one of the two live environments to boot to at boot time.

Comment: If you are lucky, someone might find such a system for you (linux with current versions of both tools). Otherwise you have to create it yourself, which is possible but much more difficult than to create a multiboot USB drive.

Comment: Install Ubuntu Persistent, It already has GParted, then install Clonezilla on the Persistent Ubuntu. Or install both to a Ubuntu minimal install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply install Ubuntu on the USB stick as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator) and install GParted and Clonezilla on it (if not already installed).